# Displaying GPS position data on map

Tags: php, javascript, gps, gis

I am developing a GPS tracking system. I have managed to develop the TCP server that captures the data in NMEA format and split it accordingly then stored the data in a mysql database. The lat and long are in Decimal Degree format. I now trying to develop a client application using PHP. How can I add/integrate a map on the application such that when you select a specific device/vehicle/asset it displays the position on a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you speak about normal web application, you can use the [Google maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) - I'd say it's the most commonly used one today.